# Node.js + Oracle 9i Database

Tags: javascript, oracle, node.js, oracle9i

I am new to node.js and I already did my research with no success, so that is my question:

It is possible to use Node.js with an Oracle 9i Database? If so, where do I find some stuff about it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The above noted npmjs now lists:**

- https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=db-oracle -> https://github.com/mariano/node-db-oracle
- https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=oracle -> https://github.com/nearinfinity/node-oracle

See also: http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/sqlplus

Comment: so... which one is recommended?  looks like node-oracle is being updated much more actively.

Comment: I have only researched to evaluate the options for a project and did not really use the drivers so I can't recommend one.

Comment: I'm partial to the "oracle" module, and have contributed a number of fixes for it.  node-db-oracle is built on top of the abstraction layer node-db, which I believe leads to a more complex design.  More importantly, the owner of "db-oracle" has not been accepting pull requests, while the owner of "oracle" has (even though he's not coding).

Comment: I have juste installed node-oracle on Windows 7 64bit, and after a bit of effort it just works !

Answer (score 2):

If there are no oracle database drivers listed in [npm registry](http://search.npmjs.org/) or within [database modules](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#database), you will probably have to write your own driver (or wait until someone writes it).

Comment: I think I'll try to write my own (open source, off course) driver. It'll be a good way to learn javascript properly.

Comment: @buenoFelipe, I'm interested in writing the oracle driver too. Did you start the project somewhere on Github by any chance?

Comment: Hey, George! I didn't start the project yet. I've been too busy last months... but let me know if u start to write it.

Comment: Finally someone wrote an oracle driver: https://github.com/mariano/node-db-oracle